# Inheritance: copy of the contents of the superclass is made within it?

Tags: java, object, inheritance, memory

*Code Below from https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/inheritance-in-java/*

```
//Java program to illustrate the 
    // concept of inheritance 

    // base class
    class Bicycle 
    {
        // the Bicycle class has two fields
        public int gear;
        public int speed;

        // the Bicycle class has one constructor
        public Bicycle(int gear, int speed)
        {
            this.gear = gear;
            this.speed = speed;
        }

        // the Bicycle class has three methods
        public void applyBrake(int decrement)
        {
            speed -= decrement;
        }

        public void speedUp(int increment)
        {
            speed += increment;
        }

        // toString() method to print info of Bicycle
        public String toString() 
        {
            return("No of gears are "+gear +"\n" + "speed of bicycle is "+speed);
        } 
    }

    // derived class
    class MountainBike extends Bicycle 
    {

        // the MountainBike subclass adds one more field
        public int seatHeight;

        // the MountainBike subclass has one constructor
        public MountainBike(int gear,int speed, int startHeight)
        {
            // invoking base-class(Bicycle) constructor
            super(gear, speed);
            seatHeight = startHeight;
        } 

        // the MountainBike subclass adds one more method
        public void setHeight(int newValue)
        {
            seatHeight = newValue;
        } 

        // overriding toString() method
        // of Bicycle to print more info
        @Override
        public String toString()
        {
            return (super.toString()+ "\nseat height is "+seatHeight);
        }

    }

    // driver class
    public class Test 
    {
                public static void main(String args[]) 
        {

            MountainBike mb = new MountainBike(3, 100, 25);
            System.out.println(mb.toString());

        }
    }
```

Hey guys,I want to double check if the statement below is right:

**when an object to My_Calculation class is created, a copy of the contents of the superclass is made within it.**

[image]

My Question is:

When a subclass inherite superclass, does it actually copy all the contents from it(which means both superclass and subclass have duplicate fields like `gear`, `speed`...etc )

**or**

`gear` and `speed` in `subclass` just are references to the `superclass` fields?

Comment: What do you mean by `copy`? Is it referred to `clone`?

Comment: @lucumt no, just simply duplicate it

Comment: Nothing is duplicated.  A `MountainBike` has only one gear and one speed.

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem thank you mate, I know that, just want to confirm if the image I attached above correct or not? (**copy of Bicycle methods and fields in MountainBike Object**)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, nothing is 'copied' to the subclass.  Your `MountainBike` is a single object with a set of fields.  Some of those fields are declared on the `MountainBike`class and some of them on its `Bicycle` superclass, but there's still only one set of fields on your object.

Run this code through the debugger in an IDE, then you can have a look at the structure of the objects.

Comment: Thank you so much, can you have a check of this page? https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_inheritance.htm. do you think it's right or wrong(the **graph** in that page) ...?

Comment: I don't agree with how the author phrases it on the tutorial - it makes it seems as though multiple objects exist.  A single object exists, of the subclass type - but because of inheritance, it is an instance of the parent class as well.  Have a look at this, the official tutorial: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html

Comment: I just checked the thinking in java, form chapter 6: **When you create an object of the derived class, it contains within it a subobject of the base class. This subobject is the same as if you had created an object of the base class by itself. It’s just that from the outside, the subobject of the base class is wrapped within the derived-class object.**.  

@Riaan Nel

Answer (score 0):

When you create an object of the derived class, it contains within it a subobject of the base class. This subobject is the same as if you had created an object of the base class by itself. It’s just that from the outside, the subobject of the base class is wrapped within the derived-class object.